# MetroUI buttoon server side Click Event

Tags: asp.net, button, metro-ui-css

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to create website. In my site, I use metroUI style, all its work well. But I have a problem with

```
<button runat="server" id="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click" class="primary">
                    <i class="icon-search on-left"></i>
                    Search
</button>
```

I need to handle Click Event of this button, but nothing happen when I clicked Button1 on my webpage.
Anyone can tell me what I have to do to handle this event on server-side? Or can use `<i class="icon-search on-left"></i>` for `<asp:button>` (I'd like to show a magnifying glass icon on this button.)
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkButton will be more useful

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkWishlist" runat="server" OnClick="btnWishlist_Click"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add to wishlist</asp:LinkButton>
```